# Ruby: simple command line with -pe is not working

Tags: ruby

file:test

```
test
```

Command line input:

```
ruby -pe 'gsub(/t([a-z])s/){"d"+$1.capitalize}' test
```

I am expecting output to be `dEt`, but the actual output is:

```
#<Enumerator:0x00000001c78520>
```

I have no idea what happen. It works in irb when I do:

```
"test".gsub(/t([a-z])s/){"d"+$1.capitalize}
```

Comment: That should work (see [`Kernel#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gsub)) but Ruby is ignoring the block. It works with the non-block form in 1.9.3 and in either form with 1.8.7.

Comment: You can use `$_.gsub!(...) { ... }` to kludge around the `ruby -pe` brain damage if necessary.

Comment: @muistooshort why is ruby ignoring the block? Is it a bug?

Comment: I would call it a bug. I haven't been able to find any official record of it yet though.

Comment: I would also vote for a bug. If explicitly supplied $_ as mu suggested, Kernel's gsub method works as described/intended.

Comment: @muistooshort I put a bug ticket. Waiting for the response now.

Comment: Do you have a link for the bug? I'm a bit curious what the fix will be.

Comment: @muistooshort Here you go: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7157 They are amazingly fast... I wasn't expecting any result , or even assignment for this issue, in the weekend, but they resolved this today and gave me a big surprise when I got up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a Ruby bug.

I submitted a bug ticket 2 days ago, and they already resolved it.

Here is the link to the bug ticket (it is now a backport):

[Backport #7157](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7157)

Here is the new change log to the trunk:

[Change log: see Oct 14](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/ChangeLog?view=markup&pathrev=37177)

Comment: Cool, I was guessing that [`rb_funcall3` should have been `rb_funcall_passing_block`](http://svn.ruby-lang.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/ruby.c?r1=37177&r2=37176&pathrev=37177) but that was just a wild guess. BTW, you can accept your own answers.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes it's exactly as you said. They changed `rb_funcall3` to `rb_funcall_passing_block`. I downloaded the new code and it's working perfectly :)